# Is there any Go port of haml or slim?

Tags: go, haml, template-engine, slim-lang

I found myself coding web stuff with Go and find the in-built template engine to be 'interesting'. I miss haml (or slim) from my Ruby projects. A quick search gave me nothing of the sort. Are there any ports of haml or slim to Go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get several entries at the top of a Google search for `haml golang`:

- https://github.com/realistschuckle/gohaml
- https://github.com/dddaisuke/go-haml
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/LmicV9aQJOw/aTY_SNkcQssJ

Comment: You can surely use it, but when it fails it's usually a good idea to look on search engines that have had more time to polish their indexing algorithms.

Answer (score 6):

Slim template engine http://slim-lang.com/ the best among template engines by reason of the simplest syntax.

https://github.com/yosssi/gold
influenced by Slim and Jade

https://github.com/eknkc/amber
inspired from HAML and Jade

https://github.com/acsellers/bham
haml-like Blocky Hypertext Abstraction Markup

https://github.com/travissimon/ghaml
haml-like language

https://github.com/a2800276/gaml
simplified haml for golang

https://github.com/bengentil/gojade
Jade Template Engine implemented by Go

Comment: The "gold" repo has been marked deprecated and visitors are directed to visit https://github.com/yosssi/ace - gold's successor - at the time of this comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check out https://github.com/yosssi/ace. Ace is a refinement of Gold as the author said.

I think the syntax is pretty similar to Slim.

Answer (score 1):

This is slim template engine for Go

https://github.com/mattn/go-slim